# one time download links

Tags: open-source, web-apps, sharing

I am looking for one-time download link software. The idea is to upload a file and have it only available for one download, for security reasons. Expiry would also be nice.

The project needs to be:

- free software (as defined by the [OSI](http://opensource.org/))
- usable with a simple web browser
- can host small text files but also arbitrarily large files
- run on a simple POSIX stack (Linux, *BSD, etc)
- a clean API would also be nice, but not mandatory
- a commandline client would be nice as well

Comment: We'll need much more information to provide a solid recommendation. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) for more detail. You say this should be a webapp - does there need to be an API? How big are the files you will be uploading? Do you have a budget?

Comment: is this sufficient?

Comment: Would it remove the files once they've been downloaded? And should it only delete the link if it's completely downloaded? You could write something reasonable in < 100 lines of Python using Flask (+Gunicorn if you're going to expect several concurrent downloads)

Comment: This is really interesting. I do know on Weebly they have this as a premium feature. Also you can set how many times the user can download their order. For example if it is an episode, file or practically anything.

Comment: @Undo and how about the answer? should i resubmit it or can you publish it back?

Answer (score 1):

here's what I found so far:

- [Jyraphe](http://home.gna.org/jyraphe/) - manages uploaded files with one link per file, text and image preview, one-time links, time-based expiration, password access restrictions, no database, written in PHP
- [Coquelicot](https://coquelicot.potager.org/) - a cleaner rewrite of Jyraphe in Ruby, with similar functionalities but also LDAP and IMAP password backends, unambiguous URLs (no "1" or "l"), original filename obfuscation, secure removal after expiration
- [0bin](https://github.com/sametmax/0bin) - all of the above, but the server also doesn't know anything about the content, which is encrypted client side
- [onetime_download](https://drupal.org/project/onetime_download) - drupal module to do something similar, albeit more limited

There's also:

- [One time secret](https://github.com/onetimesecret/onetimesecret) - useful only for small text snippets
- [Onionshare](https://onionshare.org/) - requires Tor
- [Owncloud feature request](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/7811)

Comment: There's also a feature request for fpaste (which has a command line, bundled by default in fedora): https://fedorahosted.org/fpaste/ticket/5

Comment: @Nemo that URL seems dead... does fpaste feature that now? furthermore, that's just the client side of things... the server side is https://modernpaste.com/ and it doesn't seem to support one-time links.

Comment: AWS S3 does this all ootb, but it is not free

Comment: for what it's worth, i wrote my own pastebin tool now, based on SSH, rsync and HTTPS. It just creates a "nonce" directory and throws stuff in there, showing the resulting URL. See [pubpaste](https://gitlab.com/anarcat/pubpaste) for more info.